# Add test to Gitlab pipeline

Tags: testing, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I have pushed a file (test file, pytest) to my Gitlab project, I want to show tests run in a pipeline in CI/CD of the Gitlab project.

Can anyone tell me how can I do this? I tried to add a test at the .gitlab-ci.yml file, but I’m not sure what’s the right syntax of it.

What I tried to add :

```
testing_testing:
  stage: test
  script: test_sample.py
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is GitLab official example: [lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Python.gitlab-ci.yml · GitLab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Python.gitlab-ci.yml)

In your case, add a python test in CI, you should add an image to run your python script. ex:

```
testing_testing:
  image: python:latest
  stage: test
  script: 
    - python test_sample.py
```

Comment: Thanks!
Can you please advise me with the image? I'm not sure how should I do it

Comment: do you have GitLab Runner ? or where is your Git Repo host (GitLab.com or self-host). If You used GitLab.com you should use docker image `python:latest`. If you are self-host GitLab you should add GitLab Runner (docker executor) by yourself and use docker image `python:latest`.

Comment: Yeah I'm using GitLab.com, I tried to add what you wrote up in the comment but it didn't work.

Comment: On my test_sample.py code I have "from selenium import webdriver"
Maybe GitLab doesn't support something like this?

Comment: yes, you should create your own docker to run your test. `selenium import webdriver` is e2e testing you may reference this article [End-to-end testing with GitLab CI/CD and WebdriverIO | GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/end_to_end_testing_webdriverio/) to create your .gitlab-ci.yml.